# How to get returned object using mockito framework

Tags: java, mockito, junit5

New to Mockito framework.

```
 RcExtensionInfo rcExtensionInfo = rcApiClient.get(
                RC_OFFICE_EXTENSION_INFO_API_PATH,
                pathVariablesForExtensionInfoRequest,
                customRequestHeaders,
                RcApplicationHeadersService.RcApplicationType.OFFICE_INTEGRATION,
                RcExtensionInfo.class
        );
```

The above code I need to test with mockito and I want real object of `RcExtensionInfo` because this object is being used in my code for few getter method. Currently unable to call getter method because of `null`. As we know that 
if we mock some method then default value would be `null`. But I think we can assign an object from `thenReturn` method to that reference.

Test code:

```
RcAccountInfo rcAccountInfo = new RcAccountInfo();
    rcAccountInfo.setMainNumber("+198473621");
    when(rcApiClient.get(RC_OFFICE_ACCOUNT_INFO_API_PATH,
            new HashMap<String, String>(), new HashMap<String, String>(),
            RcApplicationHeadersService.RcApplicationType.OFFICE_INTEGRATION,
            RcAccountInfo.class)).thenReturn(rcAccountInfo);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call `Mockito.mock(YourClass.class, Mockito.CALLS_REAL_METHODS)` to make it such that if nothing else is configured by `when(..).then(...)`, the real methods get called on the mocked objects.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your 4th `when` is that you use objects which will be another in your test. Because `new HashMap<String, String>()` in `when` and `new HashMap<String, String>()` in the test is not equals objects. So your `when` will never called. You should use something like this:

```
when(rcApiClient.get(RC_OFFICE_ACCOUNT_INFO_API_PATH,
        Mockito.anyMap(), Mockito.anyMap(),
        RcApplicationHeadersService.RcApplicationType.OFFICE_INTEGRATION,
        RcAccountInfo.class)).thenReturn(rcAccountInfo);
```

Comment: If you use an `ArgumentMatcher` (like `anyMap()`), Mockito requires all parameters to be `ArgumentMatcher`s, so you need to use `eq()` for the type and class arguments.